# Calling a xsl:include from inside xsl:template-match

Tags: xslt

I have an xslt where the requirement is to have a dynamically selected 'master' xslt. This 'master' xslt outputs html header information for an email, but that header varies depending on certain criteria (pst:ClientEmailTemplate in the below example).

The issue is that it isn't possible to have the following (as the xsl:include is within the xsl:template). So it is a chicken-egg situation.

What would be the best way to resolve this so I can have a dynamically selectable input xslt that is controlled by data incoming to the xslt at hand?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl pst" xmlns:pst="http://example.com/services/types">

   <xsl:template match="pst:TemplateContainer">
        <xsl:include href="{/pst:TemplateContainer/pst:Client/pst:ClientEmailTemplate}"/>
    <p>My Output text</p>

    <p>View the request <a href="{/pst:TemplateContainer/pst:Client/pst:ClientAdminUrl}/group/requests">Admin control panel</a>.</p>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: An  `xsl:include`, even in the right place, never outputs stuff on its own, so I am not sure why you would expect a header to be output by your include. You might want to show us minimal but complete samples of XML and desired output to explain what you want to achieve, then we might be able to suggest a possible XSLT way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to resolve this so I can have a dynamically
>   selectable input xslt that is controlled by data incoming to the xslt
>   at hand?

Well, not with your invention of a dynamically executed `xsl:include`, clearly. XSLT, like most modern programming languages, doesn't allow a program to modify itself at run-time.

One approach here is some kind of pipeline controlled from a different language, e.g. Java or XProc or xmlsh; the controlling program uses an XPath expression to evaluate `/pst:TemplateContainer/pst:Client/pst:ClientEmailTemplate`, and then fires off the appropriate transformation.

With XSLT 3.0, you could write the controlling program in XSLT, because you can initiate a transformation dynamically using the fn:transform() function. You might be able to achieve the same effect using vendor extensions in some non-3.0 processors.

Another approach (I don't know how feasible this is in your case) is to assemble all the possible transformations into a single XSLT stylesheet, perhaps each one using a different mode, and then select dynamically which part of this stylesheet to execute.